# OpenERP creating sub menu's in custom module

Tags: menu, module, odoo

So I have items for my custom module in my left menu bar, and I know how to order them:

```
menuitem id="*_id" name="*" parent="*" action="*_act_id" sequence="1"
```

My question is if it is possible to create sub menus.

Thank you for reading my question.
With kind regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create sub menu you need to define new menu item in your xml file. for example,

This is your existing menu,

```
<menuitem id="menu_a_id" name="Menu A" parent="Some_parent" sequence="1" />
```

Now you need to add a another menu item with parent, Here the parent of the sub menu will be the Menu A,

```
<menuitem id="menu_B_id" name="Menu B" parent="menu_a_id" action="*_act_id" sequence="1" />
```

It will give you the parent-child(hierarchical) kind of menu item.

Answer (score 0):

Add submenu to an existing menu to other module:

```
<menuitem id="name_you_want_must_be_unique" name="example"
    parent="name_of_module_of_parent_menu.id_parent_menu_"
    action="id_action_you_defineinxml_of_your_module" sequence=""/>
```